# MongoDB failover with majority write concern: Can it get into an inconsistent state?

Tags: mongodb

I have a question regarding replication and write concerns. Suppose I have a write concern of journaled + majority acknowledged, is it ever possible that in a span of two or more writes, the first write is acknowledged by the secondary 1 and not 2, AND the second write is acknowledged by secondary 2 and not 1?

And if this can happen, what will happen if a new primary has to be elected in this state?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not believe this is possible. The write operations translate into some number of entries in the oplog of the primary. The secondaries apply the operations by tailing the oplog. One of the two write operations has its last oplog entry before the other, so that operation will always be completed first by any secondary tailing the primary's oplog. Thus, the situation you describe is not possible. One of the writes had to be completely applied on a secondary before the other could've been.